# Meta tags not showing in View Source in Next.js

Tags: next.js, meta-tags

I am trying to add meta using getInitialProps or getServerSideProps(used both one by one), I am able to set the meta tags, When I inspect the page it is showing meta tags as usual, But when I open view source then It is not showing, what I am missing.

NAvbar Code :

```
<Head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossOrigin="anonymous" referrerPolicy="no-referrer" />
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            </Head>
            <Script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></Script>
            <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></Script>
            <Script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></Script>
//Navigation bar code here
```

../../partials/SEO.js :

```
import Head from 'next/head'
const Meta = (props) => (      
    <Head>
        <title>{props.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta name="og:title" property="og:title" content="" />
        <meta name="og:description" property="og:description" content={props.desc} />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="" />  
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" /> 
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content={props.desc} />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="" />
        {/* <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" /> */}
        <meta property="og:image" content="" />  
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />   
        {/* <link rel="canonical" href="" /> */}
        {/* <script type="text/javascript" src="" ></script> */}
    </Head>
)
export default Meta
```

Single Product page :

```
SingleProduct.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const { query } = context
  const { id, categoryId } = query
  var json ={
    _id : id
  }
  try{
    const respones = await fetch(Constants.getProducts, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify(json),
      });
      const result = await respones.json();
      console.log(result);
      return {
           result:  result.doc[0],
           meta_title: result.doc[0].meta_title,
           meta_desc: result.doc[0].meta_description, 
           categoryId : categoryId,
           status : 200
        }
      // return{
      //   props : {result : result.doc[0], categoryId : categoryId , status : 200}
      // }
  } catch(e){
    return {
       result: result,
       meta_title: '',
       meta_desc: '', 
       categoryId : categoryId,
       status : 404
    }
    // return{
    //   props : {result : result, categoryId : categoryId , status : 404}
    // }
  }
  
}
```

and in return function setting head :

```
{singleProductData !== null ?
      <Meta 
        title={singleProductData.name+' | ARC India'}
        desc={singleProductData.meta_description}
      />  :
      ''
    }
```

Can someone knows whats wrong here?

Comment: Where does `singleProductData` come from? Is `<Meta>` only rendered on the client-side? If so, that would explain why you're not seeing the meta tags in the source.

Comment: singleProductData  is a state variable

Comment: What's its initial value? Can you show how is `singleProductData` set? Please provide more code from the component where you're rendering `<Meta>`.

Comment: null is singleProductData initial value

Answer (score -2):

**Any dom manipulation done using JavaScript will not be visible in the view source.**

Web Crawlers like Google , bing etc. loads pages from the server. Most of the web crawlers doesn't render the pages unlike our browsers. So it won't be an issue if you are unable to see the `meta` tags.